# I have a pylint error: "W1113: keyword-arg-before-vararg" and don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, arguments, pylint

I have this code

```
class BaseCompareFeatureWithDefaults(recordlinkage.base.BaseCompareFeature):
    def __init__(self, labels_left="", labels_right="", *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(labels_left, labels_right, *args, **kwargs)
```

And I have this pylint error `W1113: Keyword argument before variable positional arguments list in the definition of __init__ function (keyword-arg-before-vararg)`. It means that pylint wants `*args, **kwargs` after `self`. I don't know how to resolve this error and should I? Might be I could skip it/disable it?

I tried to change the order to `self, *args, **kwargs, labels_left="", labels_right=""` but if I do it I have this message in VS code: `Parameter cannot follow "**" parameter Pylance` and code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named keyword arguments should come after positional varargs but before keyword varargs, i.e.:

```
def __init__(self, *args, labels_left="", labels_right="", **kwargs) -> None:
```